# Two way binding issue in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, two-way-binding

I am not able to get the two way binding in angular4 working. Here is the component code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-selector',
  templateUrl: './date-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-selector.component.css']
})
export class DateSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  private statDate: Date;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.statDate = new Date()
  }

  goToPreviousDay(): void
  {
    console.log("previous day clicked");
    this.statDate.setDate(this.statDate.getDate() - 1);
    console.log(this.statDate);
  }

  goToNextDay(): void
  {
    console.log("next day clicked");
    this.statDate.setDate(this.statDate.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(this.statDate);
  }
}
```

I am referring to statDate in my partial like this.

```
<div>
    <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" (click)=goToPreviousDay()></span></a>
    <span class="text-center text-muted" [(innerText)]="statDate"></span>
    <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" (click)=goToNextDay()></span></a>
</div>
```

Console log shows that the statDate is getting updated, but the same is not getting reflected in the UI.

Comment: statDate is declared as private, make it public

Comment: Now that you found an answer to your problem, you should accept the answer you find the most useful and relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues to be pointed out.

### Angular Binding

In your case, since we're talking about a span, all you need is one-way binding. There are several ways to do that in Angular.

The most common, readable and simple way to do this would be with an [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----). Also you are trying to display a date, so you should use Angular's [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#datepipe) like this:

```html
<span>{{statDate | date}}</span>
```

That will pretty print your date with several variables to format it like you want.

---

### HTML event binding syntax

Also your [click event binding](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events) in HTML should look like this:

```html
<span (click)="goToPreviousDay()"></span>
```

**⇨** Note the `"` after the `(click)=`, it is pretty common for the Angular code to stop its execution on HTML/TS syntax typos and that would explain the lack of UI update.

---

### Result

Combining all that is mentioned above, the resulting HTML would be:

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" (click)="goToPreviousDay()"></span>
  </a>
  <span class="text-center text-muted">{{statDate | date}}</span>
  <a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" (click)="goToNextDay()"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Also I think if you want to bind to span's property, its name is innerHTML, not innerText.

Comment: I tried this earlier. Doesnt work. All I see in the UI is the initial date string and doesnt get changed with clicks. Tried with InnerHTML as well.

Comment: @ShankarMRudraiah huh. Interesting... Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @ShankarMRudraiah, I noted something odd with your HTML code, please check my last edit (the thing about the `"`).

Comment: no errors in console. And added the quotes around fn calls as well.

Comment: I changed the {{statDate}} to {{statDate.toString()}} and it does change now:) Strange

Comment: @ShankarMRudraiah, did you try the date pipe instead?

Comment: No date pipe. just the toString() call.

Comment: @ShankarMRudraiah Ok, still I strongly recommend using the DatePipe instead. Check edit and linked Angular documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `two-way binding`, all you need here is `one-way binding`.

Change this:

```
<span class="text-center text-muted" [(innerText)]="statDate"></span>
```

to :

```
<span class="text-center text-muted" > {{ statDate }}</span>
```